# Javascript transform underscore_case to lowerCamelCase

Tags: javascript

I have an API that returns responses in `undescore_case`, and front that uses `lowerCamerlCase`. I also use NodeJS to mediate between the front and back ends.

I would like to convert any type of Javascript variable into `lowerCamelCase`, and for that I wrote this function:

```
function transform(any) {
    if(Array.isArray(any)) {
        any.forEach((v, k) => any[k] = transform(v));
    } else if(typeof any === "object" && any != null) {
        Object.keys(any).forEach(key => {
            let t = key.replace(/_\w/g, (m) => m[1].toUpperCase());
            if(t !== key) {
                any[t] = transform(any[key]);
                delete any[key];
            }
        });
    }

    return any;
}
```

It works, but I was wondering if there is any way to make it faster.

I generate this data for example:

```
let list = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    list.push({
        some_thing: {
            aa_bb: 1,
            bb_cc: 2,
            cc_dd: 3
        },
        stuff_underscore: "aaa",
        ordinary: 1
    });
```

And test using:

```
console.time("test");
transform(list);
console.timeEnd("test");
```

So, is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: If you're deserializing it yourself (using `JSON.parse`), you can change the keys during deserialization. Are you deserializing it or is a library doing that for you?

Comment: This might be better suited for CodeReview SE rather than here. Along those lines: keep it simple. Rather than a conditional check for the argument type just have one function that works on objects, then `map` it over an array of them.

Comment: I am using `JSON.parse` myself.

Comment: @JaredSmith The thing is, the API can return a number, an object, an array, an array of objects containing arrays of objects etc..

Comment: @Amit so what? Don't complicate your function with a bunch of unnecessary conditional logic. Have one function that checks the return type, and another that it calls to changes the keys. Stick to one thing per function rather than one kitchen sink function. Otherwise it has to all of the conditional checks **every time** on recursing, rather than just once when getting the return value from the API.

Comment: @JaredSmith OP is trying to write a generic function that traverses an object tree and changes the keys of the non-array objects within it. How would it know the types of the values it's processing without checking what types they are? Perhaps you could show us a fiddle with an example of what you're suggesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second parameter to `JSON.parse` to do this conversion during deserialization. This would probably save you some time compared to walking the result after deserialization:

```js
var myJson = '[{ "aa_aa": 1, "bb_bb": 2 }, { "cc_cc": 3 }]';

var obj = JSON.parse(myJson, (key, value) => {
  if (typeof value === 'object' && !Array.isArray(value)) {    Object.keys(value).forEach(keyInner => {
      let t = keyInner.replace(/_\w/g, m => m[1].toUpperCase());
      if (t !== keyInner) {
        value[t] = value[keyInner];
        delete value[keyInner];
      }
    });
  }

  return value;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Seems like a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing (at least) three things that are notoriously slow: repeating conditional checks in a loop, regular expressions, and deleting object keys.

```
const transform = obj => {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  const newKeys = keys.map(k => {
    const [first, ...rest] = k.split('_');
    return first + rest.reduce((acc, s) => {
      return acc + s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
    }, '');
  });
  return newKeys.reduce((acc, k, i) => {
    acc[k] = obj[keys[i]];
    return acc;
  }, {});
};
```

Now we are using string functions instead of regexs, constructing a new object rather than modifying one in place, and not doing any conditional checks in the transform function (those should happen before you call it).

Comment: That too looks like a step in the right direction, but how does it solve the problem for arrays, or for arrays inside objects?

Comment: Are you saying that that complicated mess of `.split` and `.reduce` is faster than `RegEx#replace`? It's certainly a lot more verbose . And are you saying that creating a whole new object from scratch is faster deleting and adding properties? Also, this doesn't fulfill OP's requirements because it doesn't process any of the property values.

Comment: For arrays, you just map it over the array. For nesting, your idea of using  recursion is correct, but you will want to move that into a separate function that calls the one I wrote. This concept is called the Single Resposibility Principle.

Comment: Just to settle this, this solution although working, on the tiny example above, takes 20-30% more time in my testing